# AttributeError in python speech recognition

Tags: python

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone as source:
   print("Say something")
   audio = r.listen(source)
   voice_data = r.recognize_google(audio)
   print(voice_data)
```

I am trying to compiling this code but it gives error like this :-

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
__enter__
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\text to speech\speech to text.py", line 5, in 
<module>
with sr.Microphone as source:
```

Answer (score 1):

Every object used in a context manager, should have an `__enter__` method and an `__exit__` method implemented in its class.
The object you are using, `sr.Microphone`, is an instance of a class that doesn't implement them.
To solve this, you should either not use a context manager (don't use the `with`), or implement the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods for `sr.Microphone`'s class.
You can find a detailed explanation about context managers in the Python documentation, or a shorter one [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/context-manager-in-python/).

Comment: Can you please explain it in detail

Comment: The only thing 'with' does, is calling the object's (`sr.Microphone`, in this case) `__enter__` method upon entering the `with`'s scope, and calling the `__exit__` method upon exiting it. In case the method `__enter__` (or `__exit__`) does not exist - you get an `AttributeError ` indicating that the method `__enter__` does not exist, just like you got

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `sr.Microphone()` you've forgot paranthesis. Remember microphone is a method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have incorrect intention. Try running after fixing indentaion:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone as source:
  print("Say something")
  audio = r.listen(source)
  voice_data = r.recognize_google(audio)
  print(voice_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @motyzk answered, the context manager should have an **enter** method and an **exit** method implemented in its class. But I believe sr.Microphone already have it. Please check if you have installed all the required libraries

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of late, but try using `sr.Microphone()` instead of `sr.Microphone`

```
>>> import speech_recognition as sr
>>> type(sr.Microphone)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(sr.Microphone())
<class 'speech_recognition.Microphone'>
```

Here you can see the difference between `sr.Microphone()` and `sr.Microphone`, as one is a type, and one is an actual instance of that type.

The type itself doesn't have methods for use in a context manager, but an instance of the class does.